# Create Html.DropDownList from Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have a need to create an invoicing function in my mvc application. I have this model class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public double costPrice { get; set; }
    public string ProductPicUrl { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

1.I need to make my view display a drop down list of all products (specifically all product names) without using ViewData
2. I need to be able to click a button that goes to my AddToInvoice controller method. I am just not sure how to make it pull the productid out of the dropdownlist and send it to the method.

Can anyone assist? Even if it is just to explain how to make the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually create a view model that contains both the model I want to create or update and the list of items required to source the data for a specific field. In this case, I would create a view model called `SelectProductModel` which contains a `ProductId` property and a `Products` property.

```
public class SelectProductModel
{

  public Int32 ProductId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

In the `Invoice` controller, I would simply load the list of products and store it in the model:

```
public ActionResult SelectProduct()
{
  SelectProductModel model = new SelectProductModel();
  model.ProductId = -1;
  model.Products = productRepository.GetList();
  return View();
}

public ActionResult AddToInvoice(Int32? id)
{
  //id is the ProductId sent
}
```

The `SelectProduct` view would be a typed view based on this model:

```
@model SelectProductModel
...
@using(Html.BeginForm(actionName="AddToInvoice", controllerName="Invoice", method=FormMethod.Post))
{

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductId, new SelectList(model.Products, "ProductId", "Name"))
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where productRepository comes from?

Comment: `productRepository` is coming from the data access layer. For the web application shouldn't matter, it should be defined as `IRepository<Product>`, where `IRepository` is a simple generic interface that defines basic `CRUD` operations. The data access layer would implement this interface and it's up to you what you use for your DAL: Entity Framework, NHibernate, ADO.NET classes, etc.